# jQuery - Outputting jquery results to a hidden form field

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how i could output the results from my jQuery to a hidden form field so i can then shove it into the database.

Im using the Calendar function found here - http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html

Apparently the following code gets the array, but im not sure how to forward it to the hidden field.

```
$('.date-picker').dpGetSelected()
```

From what i can tell i want the dpGetSelected to run with when the following is triggered dpClosed

Its all a bit confusing to me.

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to the `'dateSelected'` event to update the hidden field automatically whenever a date is selected. Assuming your hidden field has a name of "date", then:

```
$('.date-picker').bind('dateSelected', function (e, selectedDate) {
    $('input[name="date"]').val(selectedDate);
});
```

Here is the relevant demo from the plugin's website: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerListen.html

---

**Update**: To trigger the event immediately after binding so that the hidden field is correctly populated in page load:

```
$('.date-picker').bind('dateSelected', function (e, selectedDate) {
    $('input[name="date"]').val(selectedDate);
}).trigger('dateSelected', [$('.date-picker').dpGetSelected()]);
```

Comment: Sweet .. That worked .... Is there anyway to also run that when the page loads? so that it will show my pre selected dates in the hidden field?

Comment: @Cecil, sure, to reuse the above code, just trigger the `'dateSelected'` event after the `bind()`: `.trigger('dateSelected', [$('.date-picker').dpGetSelected()])`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
$("#myhiddenfieldId").val($('.date-picker').dpGetSelected());
```